# How to setup a DB connection in a server plugin

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pg-promise

I want to setup a connection to a PostgreDB in a server plugin so that I can use it whenever needed (I use pg-promise because I find named parameters more convenient).

In `~/server/plugins/connectdb.ts`:

```js
import pgPromise from 'pg-promise'
     
export default defineNitroPlugin(() => {
    console.log('Initializing DB connection')
    const pgp = pgPromise({})
    try {       
        const db = pgp('postgres://user:pwd@localhost:5432/mydb')
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error: "+error);
        return process.exit(1) 
    }
})
```

Then in `~/api/getlist.ts`:

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    console.log(db);
})
```

But here `db` is unknown. If I run a query just after the initialization, I can see the connection in Postgres' logs. I tried adding:

```js
export let db;
```

between `import` and `export default` (and change `const db` to `let db` in the code) but that doesn't change anything. I guess what I want is kind of a global variable to store the connection.

Answer (score 0):

## Using a server utility

I defined a server utility and it works (but better solution below):

`~/server/utils/dbconnect.js`

```js
import pgPromise from 'pg-promise'

const pgp = pgPromise({})
export let usePg = pgp('postgres://user:pwd@localhost:5432/mydb')
```

Then the auto-import feature does its magic and `usePg` is available everywhere.

---

## Using a server plugin

It is also possible (and preferable as it seems) to do it in a server plugin, extending the Nitro context:

in `/server/plugins/dbconnect.ts`:

```js
import pgPromise from 'pg-promise'

console.log('Init from server plugin');

export default defineNitroPlugin((nitroApp) => {
    const pgp = pgPromise({/* Initialization Options */})
    const db = pgp('postgres://user:pwd@localhost:5432/mydb')
    nitroApp.hooks.hook('request', (event) => {
        event.context.$pg = db
    })
})
```

in `/server/api/whatever.ts`:

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async event => {
    const pg = event.context.$pg

    const res = await pg.one(`
        SELECT id
        FROM passwd
        WHERE id=$(id)
        `,{id: 12})
    console.log(res);
    return res;
})
```